# AFTER UPDATE trigger gets fired AFTER INSERT - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatrigger

I have 2 datatriggers, one is supposed to fire after **update** and the other one after **insert**. This is how the beginning of the update trigger looks like:

```
    USE [Database]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTrigger]
    ON [dbo].[Table1]
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
   BEGIN
   (...)
```

The after insert trigger looks exactly the same, apart from the fact that there's AFTER INSERT instead of AFTER UPDATE. When I update the Table1, only update trigger is fired. However, when I insert, both triggers are fired. Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: Without seeing the code in both triggers, we can't determine what's going on here.

Comment: What you are describing is not possible. If a trigger is defined as AFTER UPDATE it does NOT fire after an INSERT. Can you share the code from your triggers?

Comment: If we **assume* that your insert trigger updates the same table, then that action will cause the update trigger to execute. And I'll also guess you base your observations on the effects of the update trigger without actually debugging your code to "see" the effect of the inserted trigger. Maybe the update trigger overwrites the effects of the insert trigger?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same experience as JerryBox where the separate update trigger would fire when the insert trigger fired.

What I wanted was on inserting a new record an insert trigger would insert the datetime stamp when the record was created and insert the username the record was created by. Conversely, if record was updated add/update last modified datetime and last modified by username.

In my case, when a new record was inserted into the table, the insert trigger would fire and add values to fields in the SAME TABLE (i.e. *CreatedBy* and *CreatedDateTime* fields). These additions were ‘seen’ by the update trigger as an update to an existing record so *ModifiedBy* and *ModifiedDateTime* fields would also be inserted.

In other words, inserting a new record would cause both insert and update triggers to fire.

Reading the comments on the posting by Dmitrij Kultasev, I came up with the following solution:

1. Combine both INSERT and UPDATE triggers into a single TRIGGER xxx
   ON xxx AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ...
2. Check for old records in the DELETED table
3. If records exist in DELETED table then update actions are performed
4. If no records exist in DELETED table then insert actions are
       performed

Combining both triggers into a single trigger has outcome that update of records by an AFTER INSERT trigger does not fire the AFTER UPDATE trigger.

```
USE [Database]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Data] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ModifiedDateTime] [datetime] NULL)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
       UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
       SET [ModifiedBy] = SYSTEM_USER, 
       [ModifiedDateTime] = SYSDATETIME()
       FROM inserted i 
       WHERE i.id = [dbo].[Table1].id
   ELSE
       UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
       SET [CreatedBy] = SYSTEM_USER,
           [CreatedDateTime] = SYSDATETIME()
       FROM inserted i 
       WHERE i.id = [dbo].[Table1].id
   END
GO
```

Edits: Formatting, Improved explanation in response to feedback from andronicus

Answer (score 2):

When trigger fires there are 2 virtual tables: DELETED and INSERTED. When you insert records you have the records only in INSERTED table, however when you update the record you have old records in DELETED table and new ones in the INSERTED tables. So, basically when you do UPDATE, you are doing DELETE and INSERT. You can easily solve that by identifying if there are records in DELETED table. If there are then it was UPDATE, if there is no then it was INSERT.

Comment: I've tried checking if there are any records in DELETED using the following command: IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) but the condition returned true although it was an insert. Am I using the wrong syntax maybe?

Comment: I am not sure if the problem in the syntax, but if you are saying that after insert you have records in DELETED table then something is definitely wrong

Comment: You can create 1 trigger for both inserts and updates. CREATE TRIGGER xxx ON xxx AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ...

Comment: As mentioned, you can combine both the triggers into one single trigger. If you have a different logic for the update and if you know the exact column that would be updated you can use, IF UPDATE (column).

Comment: What difference does it make, if I create 1 trigger instead of 3? I will still need to determine if it is an update or an insert in order to execute specific code for each action.